# dotnet 6.0 C# - Access to path denied

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am receiving an UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to open a file in my home directory which was initially created using the code shown below.

The initial run of this program will create the empty file "file.txt" in my home directory without issue regardless of the File.Open option (read-only or write) selected.  The code will also run when the file already exists and I select the read-only option.

I have checked the files permissions and I have full read/write access to the file and directory.  My user is listed as the owner of the file.  I have tried a different directory (C:\) and get the same error.

The program was written in C#10.0 using the latest version of VS Code and the .Net compiler 4.0.0-6.21526.21.

Error Text:

```
Press R for read-only or W for writeable: w
System.UnauthorizedAccessException says Access to the path 'C:\Users\johnc\Documents\Repositories\dotnet\C#10andDotNet6Book\Chapter03\file.txt' is denied.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException says
System.UnauthorizedAccessException says System.Private.CoreLib
System.UnauthorizedAccessException says    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\johnc\Documents\Repositories\dotnet\C#10andDotNet6Book\Chapter03\SelectionStatements\Program.cs:line 19
System.UnauthorizedAccessException says Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle CreateFile(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, System.IO.FileOptions)
```

dotnet --info:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.100
 Commit:    9e8b04bbff

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.0
  Commit:  4822e3c3aa
.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.415 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Global Usings:

```
// <auto-generated/>
global using global::System;
global using global::System.Collections.Generic;
global using global::System.IO;
global using global::System.Linq;
global using global::System.Net.Http;
global using global::System.Threading;
global using global::System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Code:

```
using static System.Console;

string path = $@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)}\Repositories\dotnet\C#10andDotNet6Book\Chapter03";

Write("Press R for read-only or W for writeable: ");
ConsoleKeyInfo key = ReadKey();
WriteLine();

Stream? s;

try
{
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.R)
    {
        s = File.Open(Path.Combine(path, "file.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
    }
    else
    {
        s = File.Open(Path.Combine(path, "file.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    }

    string message;

    switch (s)
    {
        case FileStream writeableFile when s.CanWrite:
            message = "The stream is a file that I can write to.";
            break;
        case FileStream readOnlyFile:
            message = "The stream is a read-only file.";
            break;
        case MemoryStream ms:
            message = "The stream is a memory address.";
            break;
        default:
            message = "The stream is some other type.";
            break;
        case null:
            message = "The stream is null.";
            break;
    }

    WriteLine(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    WriteLine($"{ex.GetType()} says {ex.Message}");
    WriteLine($"{ex.GetType()} says {ex.HelpLink}");
    WriteLine($"{ex.GetType()} says {ex.Source}");
    WriteLine($"{ex.GetType()} says {ex.StackTrace}");
    WriteLine($"{ex.GetType()} says {ex.TargetSite}");
}
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Did you check the directory permissions?

Comment: Yes, everything appears to be correct.  My user has full permissions to both the directory and the files below.  The ownership of the file is assigned to my user.  I can open/update/save changes to the file using a text editor (notepad).  Is there a way to capture the permissions that the dotnet compiler is seeing?  I would like to check if it sees that I have write permissions.

Comment: Try running it in admin mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!!!

Avast Antivirus File Shield was blocking file access.  Once I allowed the .exe permissions through the virus checker my code worked as expected.

Wow, that was a tough day on the computer.  Time for a refreshment!!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using Avast, as opposed to Windows Defender? Just asking because I've never had any problems with Windows Defender interfering with my own software.

Comment: No not really.  I went through a period several years ago where I wasn't too trusting in the big tech companies.  I installed it and it appeared to work fine.  To be honest, lately the daily popup ads in Avast are starting to bug me.  I just haven't gotten pissed off enough to change to something else.

Comment: Same problem, but it wasn't Avast File Shield, it was Avast Behaviour Shield!

Thanks, been wracking my brain for hours!